# Is there a destructor for plugins in case a hot restart occurs

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm writing a small flutter plugin which might currently "crash" the app, if a hot restart occurs.
I suspect this is due to my plugin attempting to open a (midi) port that was already opened in a previous run.

So I'm looking for a function that is called right before a hot restart so I can close said resources.

So far I tried flutters `ActivityAware` Interface but none of the `onDetachedFromActivityForConfigChanges`, `onDetachedFromActivity` as well as the plugins default `onDetachedFromEngine` are fired.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.